# 'actionSupport' is not working when inputField is included in same 'form'

Tags: visualforce, selectlist, actionsupport, selectoption, ui

**What I am doing ?**

I have 3 fields in an object Account(lookup to Account),User(Lookup to User) and Permissions(Multi select picklist). I needed to only show few values from all the values in permissions according to the logged-in user, thus I choose to use selectList and show only selected values.

**Where is the code ?**

```
 <apex:form >
 <apex:pageBlock title="User Permission Assignment" >
<apex:pageblockButtons >
     <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" value="Save" />
     <apex:commandButton action="{!SaveAndNew}" value="Save and New" /> 
     <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
</apex:pageblockButtons>

<apex:pageBlockSection title="Information"      columns="1" collapsible="false">
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem > Account <apex:inputField value="{!userPermissionAssignmentRecord.Account__c}" /></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem > User <apex:inputField value="{!userPermissionAssignmentRecord.User__c}" /></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem > Permission Sets
        <apex:panelGrid columns="3" id="panelGridId">
            <apex:selectList id="sel1" value="{!selectedValue}" multiselect="true" style="width:223px"  size="4">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!ToSelectValues}" id="firstOptions" />
            </apex:selectList> 
                <apex:panelGroup >
                    <br/>
                    <apex:image url="{!$Resource.SelectLogo}" height="20px" style="cursor:pointer;">
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!selectClickButton}" reRender="panelGridId"/>
                    </apex:image>
                    <br/><br/>
                    <apex:image url="{!$Resource.DeselectLogo}"  height="20px">
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!deselectClickButton}" reRender="panelGridId"/>
                    </apex:image>
                </apex:panelGroup>
            <apex:selectList id="sel2" value="{!rightselected}" multiselect="true"  style="width:223px" size="4">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!SelectedValues}" />
            </apex:selectList>               
        </apex:panelGrid>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
 </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

**What is the issue ?**

```
>  <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!selectClickButton}" reRender="panelGridId"/>
```

ActionSupport do not call the method/action selectClickButton if below input fields are included in the same form but works well if above two fields are removed.

```
 <apex:pageBlockSectionItem > Account <apex:inputField value="{!userPermissionAssignmentRecord.Account__c}" /></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem > User <apex:inputField value="{!userPermissionAssignmentRecord.User__c}" /></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

**Trouble ?**

What is it that is causing this ? How do I fix this ?

Comment: Am facing the same issue??Any resolutions for this??

Comment: Nothing so far. Code works well if put in outside that form but inside.